# Error with AWS ubuntu server connecting to FileZilla

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, sftp, amazon-web-services, filezilla

Made an Amazon web service instance today, with ubuntu server, it's working fine with apache, I can connect to the website on the browser without issues. But when I try to connect to FileZilla I get a slight irritating error, but only after it has been connected to the server 'it says'...

here is my **error messages**:

> Status:        Connecting to 54.93.71.75...
>
> Response:
>   fzSftp started, protocol_version=4
>
> Command:
>   keyfile"/Applications/Programming1/Projects/AVMG_PROJECT/name_of_secret_key.pem"
>
> Command:       open "root@54.93.71.75" 22
>
> Status:
>     Connected to 54.93.71.75
>
> Error:          Received unexpected
>   end-of-file from SFTP server
>
> Error:            Could not connect
>   to server

According to another article about similar error
messages i have done some changes to the sshd_config file on the
ubuntu server i have commented out this:

> Subsystem sftp
>   /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
>
> and replaced it with this:
>   Subsystem sftp internal-sftp

I am new to stack exchange, please let me now if any critical info is needed, and thanks beforehand

Comment: Seems to have solves this error, by changing the securtity gruop in my aws account, if any1 with similar problems, comment back and ill show you what we did